# Handling offline Network Shares When using `net use` to mount at start up

Tags: windows, command-line, mount

I'm using `net use x: "\\DEVICE\SHARE" /persistent:no` in a batch file to connect to shares at start up. However, sometimes if I am offline or if the server/device is offline the command will hang for a few minutes before failing. When I have the command running multiple times sequentially, this can take a long time. Is there a way to get computer to check that the remote device is available before trying to mount it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround that could work in your case: try to ping the device before trying to `net use` its share.

You can do that easily enough in a `.cmd` script. Here's a short example `check_if_pings.cmd` that you could adapt:

```
@echo off

ping -n 1 -w 1000 %1 > NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto failed
goto ok

:failed
echo Failed to ping %1
exit /b 1

:ok 
echo Ping %1 ok
exit /b 0
```

The `-n` parameter to `ping` specifies how many packets to send, and the `-w` how many milliseconds to wait for the reply to come. Adjust these to fit your needs.